# Can a object be instanced as null ? (php)

Tags: php

I don't understand this behavior in php (since 5.4 ? )

```
class Test {
    function __construct() {
        return null ;
    }
} ;

$a = new Test() ;
if($a) {
    echo "I am printing this. Why am I printing this ??" ;
}
```

$a should be equal NULL but it passes the test if()...

In some case (if the arguments are invalid for exemple) is it possible to get a null object when using 'new' ?

Answer (score 4):

Constructors do not return anything. After the ctor has run, the object has been created. Your `return null` is ignored.

Edit: Even if would be possible to return null in ctor when something failed it would be bad practice.

Throw an `exception` with a clear message instead.

Help page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php